# .srt subtitle files not loading for .mkv video files

Tags: windows-7, subtitles, matroska, kmplayer, gom-player

When I try play a .mkv video file in any player like VLC Player, GOM player or KMPlayer (not even on drag and drop), subtitles with .srt extension are not working for these video files in my Windows 7 machine.

What can be the possible reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Are we to assume you are using Linux? How are you loading the subtitles? Is the problem that you have `foo.mkv` and `foo.srt` in the same directory and they are not loaded automatically?

Comment: @terdon, I updated the OS in question. The way in your comment is not working + it even doesn't work if I drag and drop (KMPlayer has an option to do so) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this could be your fix but I have a Windows 10 machine, playing .mkv files with VLC player. When I couldn't get my subtitle files (.srt) to be read during the video, I either had to manually add them to the instance of the player (which didn't save for the next session) or (figured this through guessing) I changed the name of my .srt to match the .mkv file exactly (minus extension). This preloaded the .srt file every time the .mkv file was played.